# How to check what javascript function is being called in an app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to see how Google Sheets checks whether a regular expression is valid (according to the `re2` specs). For example, each time a character is entered in a regex, Google Sheets will check that the regex is valid:

[image]

[image]

How can I see what JS function or so is being called to validate the second parameter of this? I tried using the Performance tab in Chrome dev tools but was having difficulty locating the function.

Comment: They probably just use an existing library. It's also possible they do it on the server. Anyway, you can find the invariable part of the error message using devtools multi-file search, set a breakpoint in that place, walk the callstack when it triggers.

Comment: @wOxxOm right, would you want to show in an answer how that would work though?

Comment: @wOxxOm also it's not server-side, there are no network calls in it.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F, then click the file, click {} to format it, click the line number to set a breakpoint, change the formula, click the callstack, inspect the code.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Search** drawer using the **Command Menu** (`Cmd+Shift+P` or `Ctrl+Shift+P`)  > "Show Search". Search for "not a valid regular expression" and then set a breakpoint inside the function to debug the call stack.

More info:
https://www.canidev.tools/find-in-files/chrome

[image]

Comment: thanks, how would you walk the callstack though? Of course the error message isn't what checks the regex string.